# Any way to get the tag on a note (not just a page element) via OneNote REST API?

Tags: rest, onenote-api

OneNote tags on page elements (e.g. `<p>`) show up in the HTML content returned via the REST API prefixed with a `data-tag=`attribute. But if the complete note is tagged, that tag doesn't seem to show up in the returned content.

Or am I missing something?

[EDIT]
Here's a screenshot showing the complete note tagged as 'Important' (star symbol) :
[image]

I can't see anything in the returned content that relates to that tag:

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Didi Chuxing = Jean Liu</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:67px;width:576px">
            <img width="480" height="270" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/[...]
            <br />
            <p lang="en-NZ" style="font-size:14pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">credit : Fast Company</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[EDIT]
This question has led to a [UserVoice request](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/32078800-make-tags-on-the-entire-note-available-through-the) for this feature to be added in to the API. Only one vote so far - maybe this mention will get it more ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the complete note"? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @JorgeAguirre Thanks for your prompt reponse! I've attached a screenshot showing the tag on the complete note and the returned HTML not showing it.

Comment: It is clear now, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The note-tag you are showing is in the title of the page.

Currently, the OneNote API does not support returning note tags in the title. This is different to note-tags in the body, because the title tag is returned in our API as part of the HTML->head->title - other note-tags are returned within the HTML->body. I believe the right way of representing this information is to add the data-tag attribute to the HTML->head->title element.

I suggest creating a UserVoice item for this feature.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: Thanks again for following up so promptly - even if your news is disappointing ; ) I will create a UserVoice request for this addition to the API, as you suggest.

Comment: Feel free to link it here!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jorge! [Here](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/32078800-make-tags-on-the-entire-note-available-through-the)'s my UserVoice idea (with a link back to this discussion) - and I've also added it into my original post.